# Multiple model edition in django-admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have models:

```
class Lang(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    symbol = models.CharField()
    ...

class News(models.Model):
    ...
    some fields
    ...

class NewsLang(models.Model):
    news = models.ForeignKey(News)
    lang = models.ForeignKey(Lang)
    ...
    some language specific fields
    ...
```

how to do it in such a way that the admin can edit both models simultaneously, for example: select the language and edit specific data combined with models News and NewsLang?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an [InlineModelAdmin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects) e.g.

```
from django.contrib import admin

from models import News, NewsLang

class NewsLangInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = NewsLang

class NewsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [NewsLangInline]
admin.site.register(News, NewsAdmin)
```